# Can I grant cloudfunctions.functions.call on a specific function?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

[Cloud Functions IAM Permissions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/permissions) specifies the permissions that can be granted upon cloud functions. I believe I'm correct in saying that if permission `cloudfunctions.functions.call` is granted then the grantee can call any function in the project. Is it possible to grant `cloudfunctions.functions.call` on a specific function only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#adding_users) both in Console and with Cloud SDK.

Command for latter will look like this:

```
gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding FUNCTION_NAME \
  --member=MEMBER_TYPE \
  --role=ROLE
```

Comment: Much appreciated. Also glad to see that the same is supported via the terraform GCP provider, which is what we are using to create GCP resources https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudfunctions_cloud_function_iam#google_cloudfunctions_function_iam_member